# Unable to print console output in same format onto text document

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I have my java file set up to calculate a phone bill and print out to the console in this format.

```
Invoice
--------------------------
Account   Amount Due 
10011      $12.25
10033      $11.70
--------------------------
Total      $23.95
```

but when I run the program I only get this on the text file

```
Account Amount_Due
10011 $12.25
10033 $11.7
```

Can someone help me edit my filecreating code in correct format?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;


public class PhoneBill {
    Vector data;
    Vector processed = new Vector();

    Vector markProcessed = new Vector();
    public void readFile(String inFileStr)
    {
        String str = "";
        data = new Vector<LineItem>();
        FileReader fReader;
        InputStream inFileStream;
         try{
        fReader = new FileReader(inFileStr);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fReader);
            String line;
            while ((line=br.readLine())!= null){
                if (line.indexOf("_") != -1)
                    continue;
                else
                  if (!line.isEmpty()){
                    data.add(new LineItem(line.trim()));

                  }
            }

            br.close(); 
        }       
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
    public void processCharges()
    {
        String out = "Account Amount_Due\n";
        System.out.println ("Invoice");
        System.out.println ("--------------------------");
        System.out.println ("Account   " + "Amount Due ");
        double total = 0.0;
        double lCharges =0;
        boolean done = false;
        DecimalFormat numFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$##.##");
        for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++ ){
            LineItem li =  (LineItem)data.get(j);
            String accNum = li.getAccountNum();
            if (j > 0){
                done = checkProcessed(accNum);}
            else
                processed.add(accNum);
            if (!done){
                   lCharges = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
              String acc = ((LineItem)data.get(i)).getAccountNum();
              if (acc.equals(accNum) && !done)
              lCharges += processItemCharges(accNum);
              done = checkProcessed(accNum);
            }
            lCharges+=10.0;
            System.out.format ("%s" + "      $%.2f%n",accNum, lCharges);
            out += accNum+" ";
            out += numFormatter.format(lCharges)+"\n";
            processed.add(accNum);

             total += lCharges;
            }

        }

        System.out.println ("--------------------------");
        System.out.format ("%s" + "      $%.2f%n","Total", total);
        writeToFile("invoice.txt", out);

    }
    private void writeToFile(String filename,String outStr)
    {
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(outStr);
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

    }
    private boolean checkProcessed(String accNum){
        if (processed.contains(accNum))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    private double processItemCharges(String accNum)
    {
        double charges = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            if(((LineItem)data.get(i)).getAccountNum().equals(accNum))
                charges += ((LineItem)data.get(i)).getCharges();
        }
        return charges;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PhoneBill pB =  new PhoneBill();
        pB.readFile("input_data.txt");
        pB.processCharges();
    }

    class LineItem{
        String accNum ;
        String timeOfCall;
        double mins;
        double amountDue;
        boolean counted = false;

        public LineItem(String accStr)
        {
            processAccount(accStr);
        }

        private void processAccount(String accStr){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(accStr);
            accNum = (String)st.nextElement();
            timeOfCall = (String) st.nextElement();
            mins = Double.parseDouble((String) st.nextElement());
            if (timeOfCall.compareTo("08:00")>0 && timeOfCall.compareTo("22:00")<0)
                amountDue = mins*0.10;
            else
                amountDue = mins*0.05;
        }

        public String getAccountNum()
        {
            return accNum;
        }

        public double getCharges()
        {
            return amountDue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You just don't append everything you write to `System.out` to the String `out`, also you should use a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`.

Comment: You're both printing, and appending to a string which is written. The two don't go to the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study this.  It uses a bit more advanced Java but understanding it will be well worth your while.

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PhoneBill {

    private static String BILL_FORMAT = "%-10s $%,6.2f\n";
    private static boolean DEBUG=true;

    Map<String, List<LineItem>> accounts = new HashMap<String,List<LineItem>>();

    public void readFile(String inFileStr) {
        FileReader fReader=null;
        try {
            fReader = new FileReader(inFileStr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.indexOf("_") != -1)
                    continue;
                else if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    LineItem li = new LineItem(line.trim());
                    List<LineItem> list = accounts.get(li.accNum);
                    if(list==null){
                        list = new ArrayList<LineItem>();
                        accounts.put(li.accNum, list);
                    }
                    list.add(li);
                }
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* Don't just swallow Exceptions. */
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { 
            if(fReader!=null){
                try{
                    fReader.close();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void processCharges() {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer(100)
            .append("Invoice\n")
            .append("--------------------------\n")
            .append("Account   Amount Due \n");
        double total = 0.0;
        double lCharges = 0;

        for (String accNum:accounts.keySet()) {
            List<LineItem> account = accounts.get(accNum);
            lCharges = 10;
            for(LineItem li:account){
                lCharges += li.getCharges();
            }
            total += lCharges;
            out.append(String.format(BILL_FORMAT, accNum, lCharges));
        }

        out.append("--------------------------\n");
        out.append(String.format(BILL_FORMAT, "Total", total));
        writeToFile("invoice.txt", out.toString());

    }

    private void writeToFile(String filename, String outStr) {
        if(DEBUG){
            System.out.printf("========%swriteToFile:%s=========\n", '=', filename);
            System.out.println(outStr);
            System.out.printf("========%swriteToFile:%s=========\n", '/', filename);
        }
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);

            // If file doesn't exist, then create it.
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(outStr);
            bw.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PhoneBill pB = new PhoneBill();
        pB.readFile("input_data.txt");
        pB.processCharges();
    }

    static class LineItem {
        String accNum;
        double timeOfCall;
        double mins;
        double amountDue;
        boolean counted = false;

        private static final double EIGHT_AM = convertTime("08:00");
        private static final double TEN_PM = convertTime("22:00");

        public LineItem(String accStr) {
            processAccount(accStr);
        }

        private void processAccount(String accStr) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(accStr);
            accNum = st.nextToken();
            timeOfCall = convertTime(st.nextToken());
            mins = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
            if (timeOfCall > EIGHT_AM && timeOfCall < TEN_PM)
                amountDue = mins * 0.10;
            else
                amountDue = mins * 0.05;
        }

        public String getAccountNum() {
            return accNum;
        }

        public double getCharges() {
            return amountDue;
        }

        private static double convertTime(String in){
            /* Will blow up if `in` isn't given in h:m. */
            String[] h_m = in.split(":");
            return Double.parseDouble(h_m[0])*60+Double.parseDouble(h_m[1]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ElementException?  What is that?  Can you show me a stack trace?

Comment: `java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
 at ShortProjects.PhoneBill$LineItem.processAccount(PhoneBill.java:119)
 at ShortProjects.PhoneBill$LineItem.<init>(PhoneBill.java:114)
 at ShortProjects.PhoneBill.readFile(PhoneBill.java:24)
 at ShortProjects.PhoneBill.main(PhoneBill.java:99)`

Answer (score 0):

Printing to the console (i.e. System.out.println) is not the same as concatenating to your out variable (i.e. out+=).

So when you call

```
writeToFile("invoice.txt", out);
```

You are only writing what is in the string 'out' to the file. If you look back at your code, you'll see that all of your missing lines are only ever printed to the console, but not concatenated to the 'out' variable. Correct that and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: i see what you mean. Can u suggest a way you could fix this?

Comment: Yes. In your `processCharges()` method. Look for every time that you use a `System.out.println("some string")` line. Immediately after each of those lines, add a line like `out+="some string"`;